# Backup and restore clonezilla linux image into a new windows based laptop

Tags: backup, restore, clonezilla

my current office laptop ( that died recently ) is configured with dual boot windows/xubuntu, because company laptop comes by default with windows. Luckily the hard disk is fine.

Now the new laptop is coming and again will arrive with windows by default.

What is the correct steps to backup my current xubuntu partition and restore it into the new laptop, keeping the existing windows installation and automatically be aware of dual boot options?

Comment: Maybe it is easiest (and fastest too) to make a fresh dual boot installation of Xubuntu into the new computer. If you wish, you can copy the content of the `/home` directory tree into a 'home' partition, and select 'Something else' at the partitioning page (during the installation) and use that partition as `/home` in order to keep settings and tweaks, that belong to the the user IDs. But this way you have to reinstall the installed programs and redo the global tweaks (if any).

Comment: I know it's clearer and fastest this way... But I have too many programs and configurations to set.. That I even don't remember how

Comment: Asking how to backup Windows is off-topic here.

Comment: In that case you can try by cloning the partition(s) of your old Xubuntu system and install the bootloader separately (pointing to the cloned copies of the partitions). -- It is fairly easy to clone the whole drive, but more complicated to clone only some partitions and fix the bootloader to work with the cloned Xubuntu and the new Windows.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro didn't ask how to backup windows

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully restored the xubuntu system, keeping the dual boot options, following these steps;

1. Create a clonezilla image of my xubuntu partition
2. Install a temporary minimal debian distribution, and during installation create the ext4 partition big enough to contain my "old" xubuntu partition
3. Start the system with clonezilla boot iso and restore xubuntu image over ext4 partition, erasing the minimal debian
4. Once restored run update-grub

For now all seems ok, only problem I have is the ubuntu splash logo won't show up, but persist the text version of boot up logo. Re-installing plymouth didn't help.

All this operations have been done on a virtualbox virtual machine, but should be fine also on new laptop.

I'm open to better solutions.